# How do I initialize a stl vector of objects who themselves have non-trivial constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, initialization-list

suppose I have the following class:

```
class MyInteger {
private:
  int n_;
public:
  MyInteger(int n) : n_(n) {};
  // MORE STUFF
};
```

And suppose this class don't have a default trivial constructor `MyInteger()`. I must always supply an `int` to initialize it for some reason. And then suppose that somewhere in my code I need a `vector<MyInteger>`. How do I initialize each `MyInteger` component in this `vector<>`?

I have two situations (probably the solution is the same, but I'll state them anyway), a normal variable inside a function:

```
int main(){
    vector<MyInteger> foo(10);  //how do I initialize each 
                                //MyInteger field of this vector? 
    doStuff(foo);
}
```

and as data in a class:

```
class MyFunClass {
private:
   vector<MyInteger> myVector;

public:
   MyFunClass(int size, int myIntegerValue) : myVector(size) {}; 
   // what do I put here if I need the 
   // initialization to call MyInteger(myIntegerValue) for all 
   // components of myVector?
};
```

Is it possible to do it just in the initialization list or must I write the initialization by hand in the MyFunClass(int, int) constructor?

This seems so very basic, and yet I somehow missed it inmy book and can't find in the web.

Comment: Should the integer be the same for all instances inside the vector?

Comment: It's good enough. I just want to learn how to initialize the vector. The real code where this doubt appeared is not exactly this. I just wanted a simple code with the same problem.

Comment: In my real code I have a vector of graphs and a class which is a collection of graphs, and I'm using a `vector<Graph>` as a container. The problem is that the number of graphs in the collection must be the same as the size of the Graphs, so I must pass to the Graph constructor the same `int` I pass to the vector constructor.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are many ways to get there. Here are some of them (in no particular order of presence).

Use `vector(size_type n, const T& t)` constructor. It initializes vector with `n` copies of `t`. For example:

```
#include <vector>

struct MyInt
{
    int value;
    MyInt (int value) : value (value) {}
};

struct MyStuff
{
    std::vector<MyInt> values;

    MyStuff () : values (10, MyInt (20))
    {
    }
};
```

Push elements into vector one by one. This might be useful when values should be different. For example:

```
#include <vector>

struct MyInt
{
    int value;
    MyInt (int value) : value (value) {}
};

struct MyStuff
{
    std::vector<MyInt> values;

    MyStuff () : values ()
    {
        values.reserve (10); // Reserve memory not to allocate it 10 times...
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            values.push_back (MyInt (i));
        }
    }
};
```

Another option is constructor initialization list, if C++0x is an option:

```
#include <vector>

struct MyInt
{
    int value;
    MyInt (int value) : value (value) {}
};

struct MyStuff
{
    std::vector<MyInt> values;

    MyStuff () : values ({ MyInt (1), MyInt (2), MyInt (3) /* ... */})
    {
    }
};
```

Of course, there is an option to provide default constructor and/or use something other than `std::vector`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hum! Does g++ support C++0x yet?

Comment: Now that it's 2017, I'd probably start with the C++11 initialization example.

Comment: Alternatively, in the member initialization list of MyStuff's default ctor, you can use uniform initialization like so: `MyStuff () : values{ {1}, {2}, {3} } {}`

Answer (score 13):

If the elements of the vector are not default-constructible, then there are certain things you cannot do with the vector.  You cannot write this (example 1):

```
vector<MyInteger> foo(10);
```

You can, however, write this (example 2):

```
vector<MyInteger> foo(10, MyInteger(37));
```

(This only requires a copy constructor.)  The second argument is an initializer for the elements of the vector.

In your case, you could also write:

```
vector<MyInteger> foo(10, 37);
```

...since MyInteger has a non-explicit constructor taking "int" as argument.  So the compiler will cast 37 to MyInteger(37) and give the same result as example 2.

You might want to study the [documentation on std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/).

Answer (score 6):

```
vector<MyInteger> foo(10, MyInteger(MY_INT_VALUE));

MyFunClass(int size, int myIntegerValue) : myVector(size, MyInteger(myIntegerValue)) {};
```

Answer (score 5):

Besides all answers which answered the question very well, in a case that your class MyInteger is not copy-constructible, you could use this trick : instead of creating `vector< MyInteger>`, you could create `vector< shared_ptr< MyInteger > >`

Answer (score 1):

Initialization lists can be used without reference to the underlying objects.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class Test
{
   public:
   struct NumStr
   {
      int num;
      string str;
   };

   Test(vector<int> v1,vector<NumStr> v2) : _v1(v1),_v2(v2) {}
   vector<int> _v1;
   vector<NumStr> _v2;
};

int main()
{
   Test t={ {1,2,3}, {{1,"one"}, {2,"two"}, {3,"three"}} };
   cout << t._v1[1] << " " << t._v2[1].num << " " << t._v2[1].str << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

output: 2 2 two